# Want Applescript to change a Keynote presentation to a particular slide

Tags: applescript

I'm a newbie with Applescript, but can Applescript tell Keynote to display a specific slide out of order during a presentation?  Don't want to advance in sequence, but I do want to specify a specific slide in random order.

I tried the Apple documentation, but nothing there.  Not of the similar questions here really answers this question.  The MacScripters site suggestion (below) didn't work.

NOT WORKING (this, after having Applescript start Keynote and launch slideshow presentation:

```
tell application "Keynote" to show (slide 22 of "/Users/me/Documents/Keynote_Slides.key")
end tell
```

Also tried, but NOT WORKING

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Keynote"
        jump to 22
    end tell
end tell
```

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work for you I think:

```
tell application "Keynote"
tell slideshow 1
    show slide 22
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Many thanks Ian. I do have one follow on question, what is the purpose of the "tell slideshow 1"?  Why "1"?  One would think you should use the Keynote filename.  Again a newbie and the documentation doesn't exactly explain.

Comment: You don't have to use "tell slideshow 1", it was just the easiest way of simply presenting an answer. The key thing is that you need to tell the slideshow to show the slide rather than just telling  the Keynote application to show the slides. When you interface with the slideshows you will also need to use an appropriate method for getting the correct slideshow. If you look up slideshows in the Applescript Dictionary for keynote you will see there are limited ways of identifying a specific slidewshow.