# How to remotely trigger Applescript for Keynote on a MacBook from an iPad

Tags: ipad, triggers, applescript, keynote

I am trying to figure out if I can remotely control KeyNote running on a MacBook (connected to video projection system) from an iPad. Specifically, when lecturing, I would like to be able to create a trigger in my notes that would let me tap and jump to a specific keynote slide out of sequence.

I noted the Applescript given for jumping to a slide out of sequence (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726444/want-applescript-to-change-a-keynote-presentation-to-a-particular-slide). That is helpful but I'm still missing a piece.

What I don't know is if/how I can remotely trigger such an applescript on the laptop from an ipad. So far haven't turned up any answers but I'm a newbie so maybe I'm not searching it out correctly. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 simple ways.

1) screen sharing. The iPad has screen sharing apps that you can use to view the screen of your mac and basically control it from the iPad.

2) ssh. There's also ssh apps for the iPad so you can ssh into the mac. From the command line you can run applescripts using the osascript command line tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I'm not just looking for a way to remote access the laptop. I want to be able to embed icons into the body of  lecture outline on the ipad which, when tapped, would tell the keynote presentation running the laptop to jump to the relevant slide. Obviously that does require a certain level of remote access. I want the notes resident on the iPad since there are times I give the same lectures without using keynote slides so would not be using the laptop.

Comment: The only other solution I could think of is if you had a web server running on the laptop. Then you could have web links embeded in your outline, which connect to the web server on the laptop when clicked, and depending on the particular link you tap your website could be setup to run different applescripts. That's a tough thing to implement though. I think the 2 suggestions I gave are very simple and would be effective. Good luck though.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give all of that some thot.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Eventscripts](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html).
It has a server app for triggers as well as remote execution from the ios app which also receives customized icons.