# Using Applescript run powerpoint slide show of specified slide in the presentation

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, powerpoint

I want to run PowerPoint slide show for only a particular slide.
After my research, I tried following but I did not get expected result.
Both of the scripts, starts slide show but from the first slide.

1)

```
`tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    open "/Users/sanjeev/pppp.ppt"
    set slideShowSettings to slide show settings of active presentation
    set starting slide of slideShowSettings to 4
    set ending slide of slideShowSettings to 4
    run slide show slideShowSettings
end tell`
```

2)

```
`tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    open "/Users/sanjeev/pppp.ppt"
    set slideShowSettings to slide show settings of active presentation
    run slide show slideShowSettings
    go to slide slide show view of slide show window 1 number 4
end tell`
```

The second script gives an error also:
error "Microsoft PowerPoint got an error: slide show view of slide show window 1 doesn’t understand the go to slide message." number -1708 from slide show view of slide show window 1

I saw a question [Want Applescript to change a Keynote presentation to a particular slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726444/want-applescript-to-change-a-keynote-presentation-to-a-particular-slide)
But I think that works only for KeyNote.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work. It looks buggy to me. When the script is run the screen goes black, then flashes the slide then goes black then finally displays the slide. I don't know if this is due to the script or the implementation of Applescript/ppt from Microsoft. I say the latter.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    set temp to active presentation's slide show settings
    set temp's starting slide to 2
    set temp's ending slide to 2
    set temp's range type to slide show range
    set temp's advance mode to slide show advance manual advance
    run slide show temp
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is working great. Any idea, if we can close the presentation opened in background, while running its slideshow.

Comment: The presentation's window needs to be opened for the presentation to run.