# Jumping to keynotes slides out of sequence

Tags: applescript, keynote

Using Keynote, I would like slide 6 to jump back to slide 2. I found applescript code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6726444/) that works to direct jumps:

```
tell application "Keynote"
tell slideshow 1
    show slide 2
end tell
end tell
```

I don't understand how to activate this from slide 6. Can I embed this in the #6 slide?

Answer (score 1):

No AppleScript needed to jump to another slide.
In this case, a picture is more than a thousand words:

[image]

If you want to re-show some slide out of sequence at another point in your presentation, the simplest obvious way would be to just duplicate that slide and place the copy where you need it. But that, of course, will probably mess with your slide numbers.

Alternatively, you could use an AppleScript similar to the one you mention in the question to run your entire presentation. This simple solution, of course, would only make sense if the presentation were more something of a slideshow, with a fixed duration per slide and without the need of manually interacting / switching between the slides:

```
set duration to 10 -- number of seconds per slide
set slideSequence to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7} -- re-show slide #2 between #6 and #7

tell application "Keynote" to tell slideshow 1
    repeat with slideNumber in slideSequence
        show slide slideNumber
        delay duration
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Oh, by the way: Keynote '09 (version 5.1.1)

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is very helpful. Is it possible to get the slide 6 to jump to slide 6 without user interaction? Say after some time delay.

Comment: I don't think there's a way of automatically jumping to a slide out of sequence by delay (and I couldn't find a way of auto-triggering an AppleScript from a presentation, either.) But consider one of the possibilities given in the edited answer.